# error with importing a file error.js errors:477 NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting an error when importing errors.js, to use it in app.js. I guess I'm exporting it in a wrong way. I have tried to export it as constant and among other options but it always shows me error. I think I am exporting the errors.js file wrong but I have not yet figured out how to fix it or do it in a consistent way so that the error is removed.

errors.js

```
import ErrorHandler from '../utils/erroHandler';

export default (err, req, res, next) => {
    err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
    err.message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEVELOPMENT') {
        res.status(err.statusCode).json({
            success: false,
            error: err,
            errMessage: err.message,
            stack: err.stack,
        });
    }

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION') {
        let error = {...err};

        error.message = err.message;

        // Wrong Mongoose Object ID Error
        if (err.name === 'CastError') {
            const message = `Resource not found. Invalid: ${err.path}`;
            error = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
        }

        // Handling Mongoose Validation Error
        if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            const message = Object.values(err.errors).map(
                (value) => value.message
            );
            error = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
        }

        // Handling Mongoose duplicate key errors
        if (err.code === 11000) {
            const message = `Duplicate ${Object.keys(err.keyValue)} entered`;
            error = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
        }

        // Handling wrong JWT error
        if (err.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
            const message = 'JSON Web Token is invalid. Try Again!!!';
            error = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
        }

        // Handling Expired JWT error
        if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
            const message = 'JSON Web Token is expired. Try Again!!!';
            error = new ErrorHandler(message, 400);
        }

        res.status(error.statusCode).json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message || 'Internal Server Error',
        });
    }
};
```

App.js

```
import express from 'express';
import productsRouter from './routes/products.routes.js';
import errors from './middlewares/errors.js'; //import ---
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api', productsRouter);

export default app;
```

ERROR

````
node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Fanta\Desktop\Trabajo y estudio\MinTic\Ciclo 4\Programacion\VetyShop\backend\utils\erroHandler' imported from C:\Users\Fanta\Desktop\Trabajo y estudio\MinTic\Ciclo 4\Programacion\VetyShop\backend\middlewares\errors.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:429:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1006:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1214:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:165:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:844:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:431:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong
````

Comment: Can you also show the full path for both files?

Comment: What do you mean? I will upload an image showing where each one is located if it helps.

Comment: Are you using VS Code? If so, I believe you can right click on the file and copy the file's path. It will be something like  `C:\Users\Fanta\Desktop\Trabajo y estudio\MinTic\Ciclo 4\Programacion\VetyShop\backend\middlewares\errors.js` (but I suspect it will be slightly different -- and if that's true, then that would be the cause of the error since the file path wasn't correct)

Comment: As a guess, maybe you meant `import errors from './middleware/errors.js';` instead of `import errors from './middlewares/errors.js';`? We'll know for sure once you share the full file paths for both files.

Comment: I managed to fix it, inside error.js there was something that was imported. Thanks, you made me analyze the routes well and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

not working example:

```
import foo from "./foo.js"
```

this will throw error that foo.js.js / foo.js.cjs / foo.js.mjs does not exist.

don't write the extensions while importing.

```
import foo from "./foo"
```

this will find foo.js/foo.cjs/foo.mjs.

Comment: no brother, what you just suggested did not work.

Comment: Hey Dariush! Hope all is well with you! Great seeing you here -- and missing you in the Frontend Gathering Spot meetings :)

Comment: Heyy! What a tiny world! as a crazy coincidence case, ReasonML reminded me of you yesterday and now here we bumped into each other! I highly miss our gatherings, too.

Comment: Feel free to reach out on Twitter (https://twitter.com/RRafatpanah) if you ever want to catch up.